# How to add custom filed and save it in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

Following code I tried out But it is not save value of custom Fileds.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );
 function cd_meta_box_add()
{
add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'My First Meta Box', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'product', 'side', 'high' );
}
```

In above I have add code it is display when posttype is product

```
function cd_meta_box_cb( $product)
{
  $values = get_post_custom( $product->ID );
  $text = isset( $values['my_meta_box_text'] ) ? esc_attr($values['my_meta_box_text'][0] ) : ”;

?>
<p>
 <label for="my_meta_box_text">Text Label</label>
<input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text" id="my_meta_box_text" value="<?php echo $text; ?>" />
    </p>
<?php        
}
```

In above code it will added the metabox with textbox and if value in metabox then it is display

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
function cd_meta_box_save( $product_id )
{
// Bail if we're doing an auto save
if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

// if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

// if our current user can't edit this post, bail
if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;
}
```

I want to save data in a wp_postmeta table. Above code i have tried out. I am beginner in wordpress.Can any give me suggestion ?

Comment: Can you please check if Form is submitted or not , when you save ? if yes, please echo the value of `$_REQUEST` to check if you are getting all data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This code for creating custom fields for post.

```
  class Rational_Meta_Box {
        private $screens = array(
            'post',
        );
        private $fields = array(
            array(
                'id' => 'custom-field-1',
                'label' => 'custom field 1',
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 'custom-field-2',
                'label' => 'custom field 2',
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
        );

/**
 * Class construct method. Adds actions to their respective WordPress hooks.
 */



    public function __construct() {
            add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ) );
            add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_post' ) );
        }

    /**
     * Hooks into WordPress' add_meta_boxes function.
     * Goes through screens (post types) and adds the meta box.
     */



public function add_meta_boxes() {
    foreach ( $this->screens as $screen ) {
        add_meta_box(
            'my-custom-fields',
            __( 'my custom fields', 'wordpress' ),
            array( $this, 'add_meta_box_callback' ),
            $screen,
            'advanced',
            'high'
        );
    }
}

    /**
     * Generates the HTML for the meta box
     * 
     * @param object $post WordPress post object
     */



public function add_meta_box_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_custom_fields_data', 'my_custom_fields_nonce' );
    echo 'its for custom fields for post typle';
    $this->generate_fields( $post );
}

    /**
     * Generates the field's HTML for the meta box.
     */


    public function generate_fields( $post ) {
            $output = '';
            foreach ( $this->fields as $field ) {
                $label = '<label for="' . $field['id'] . '">' . $field['label'] . '</label>';
                $db_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_custom_fields_' . $field['id'], true );
                switch ( $field['type'] ) {
                    default:
                        $input = sprintf(
                            '<input %s id="%s" name="%s" type="%s" value="%s">',
                            $field['type'] !== 'color' ? 'class="regular-text"' : '',
                            $field['id'],
                            $field['id'],
                            $field['type'],
                            $db_value
                        );
                }
                $output .= $this->row_format( $label, $input );
            }
            echo '<table class="form-table"><tbody>' . $output . '</tbody></table>';
        }

        /**
         * Generates the HTML for table rows.
         */
        public function row_format( $label, $input ) {
            return sprintf(
                '<tr><th scope="row">%s</th><td>%s</td></tr>',
                $label,
                $input
            );
        }
        /**
         * Hooks into WordPress' save_post function
         */
        public function save_post( $post_id ) {
            if ( ! isset( $_POST['my_custom_fields_nonce'] ) )
                return $post_id;

            $nonce = $_POST['my_custom_fields_nonce'];
            if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'my_custom_fields_data' ) )
                return $post_id;

            if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
                return $post_id;

            foreach ( $this->fields as $field ) {
                if ( isset( $_POST[ $field['id'] ] ) ) {
                    switch ( $field['type'] ) {
                        case 'email':
                            $_POST[ $field['id'] ] = sanitize_email( $_POST[ $field['id'] ] );
                            break;
                        case 'text':
                            $_POST[ $field['id'] ] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ $field['id'] ] );
                            break;
                    }
                    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_custom_fields_' . $field['id'], $_POST[ $field['id'] ] );
                } else if ( $field['type'] === 'checkbox' ) {
                    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_custom_fields_' . $field['id'], '0' );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    new Rational_Meta_Box;
```

So it will create custom fields in your post type and also saved it too.

follow this for the references https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/creating-custom-meta-boxes/

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' ); function and put below code.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
function cd_meta_box_save( $product_id )
{
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'my_meta_box_text' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $product_id,'my_meta_box_text', $_POST['my_meta_box_text'] );
    }
}
```

Full code like ( it's working fine and also save custom field in postmeta table)

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );
 function cd_meta_box_add()
{
add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'My First Meta Box', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'post', 'side', 'high' );

}

function cd_meta_box_cb( $product)
{
  $values = get_post_custom( $product->ID );
  $text = isset( $values['my_meta_box_text'] ) ? esc_attr($values['my_meta_box_text'][0] ) : '';

?>
<p>
 <label for="my_meta_box_text">Text Label</label>
<input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text" id="my_meta_box_text" value="<?php echo $text; ?>" />
    </p>
<?php        
}


add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
function cd_meta_box_save( $product_id )
{

    if( isset( $_POST[ 'my_meta_box_text' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $product_id,'my_meta_box_text', $_POST['my_meta_box_text'] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Pods.
It is a very powerful plugin for customization.
http://pods.io/

Comment: I don't want to use plugin.